# Django-q how to delete scheduled tasks

Tags: django, django-q

I'm using django-q to schedule monthly event for sending emails. After several testing runs, I realized that each time I execute the:

```
Schedule.objects.create(func='app.email.send_monthly_email',schedule_type=Schedule.MONTHLY,repeats=-1)
```

this schedule event is cached and it will run the next time I start qcluster. How to I delete all the scheduled tasks in django-q? Or how can I have a clean start every time I run qcluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the database shell using

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

And then use an SQL command :

```
DELETE FROM django_q_schedule
```

Remember that this will delete **All Scheduled Tasks**

Answer (score 0):

Open Django ORM Shell

```
from django_q.models import Schedule
```

Here, you can see all your scheduled jobs

```
Schedule.objects.all()
```

To delete,

```
job = Schedule.objects.get(id=<job_id>)
job.delete()
```